# What is it called: a hairpin or a hairgrip?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

This is a hairpin
[image]

[hairpin](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hairpin?q=hairpin): ​a small thin piece of wire that is folded in the middle, used by women for holding their hair in place

This is a hairgrip
[image]

[hairgrip](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hairgrip): a small thin piece of metal or plastic folded in the middle, used by women for holding their hair in place

**But what about this** 
[image]

Is it called **a hairpin or a hairgrip**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't hairpins, hair grips (not an Am.E. usage, for the record)  or hair clips.

They're foam **[hair rollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_roller)**.

Comment: What is its function? to make your hair curl?

Comment: @Tom Yes. There are electric heated ones, but the ones in your picture are just foam. You put them in your hair and leave them for a while, and they make curls/waves when you take them out. Unlike pins or clips, which would likely be kept in to keep the hairstyle secure, hair rollers are always taken out before going out into public.

Comment: As a British English speaker I would call the first object a _hairgrip_ or _Kirby grip_ (apparently the Americans call them _bobby pins_). A _hairpin_ is similar but with a wider curve and the two ends not touching (we call a very tight curve in a road a _hairpin bend_). I would call the decorative item a _hair clip_.

Comment: See [this](https://www.humblebeeandme.com/meet-hair-pins-bobby-pins-far-more-useful-sister/)

Answer (score 0):

These are [hair rollers](https://www.womanandhome.com/beauty/how-to-use-hair-rollers-heated-rollers-velcro-rollers-206010/). See the link for an explanation of how to use them :-)